# Trouble connecting to MongoDB and creating a new Collections folder through Node / Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was following the tutorial of [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/o3ka5fYysBM?t=3928) in order to build an API that would connect and interact with my Mongo database. The progress was going great until I got to the part referenced in the link (1:05:20).

This is the code the tutorial creator utilized.

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose')
const server = 'ds221609.mlab.com:21609'
const database = 'rest-api-workshop'
const user = 'username'
const password = 'password'

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${user}:${password}@${server}/${database}`)

let CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    requried: true,
    unique: true
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema)
```

I obviously swapped around credentials with the ones for my mongodb user, but was still unable to get it to work.
Furthermore, the format given by mongodb now seems very different:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<databaseID>.azure.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

My goal is to basically create a new record under the "customers" folder of my db collections. How do I accomplish this in 2019?